# Too much nesting

Tags: php

I'm putting together a little application and it requires about 6 `if` statements to verify actions, here's the code I'm using:

```
if($player[0]['value'] == $server->clean_attr($row['attr1'])) {
    if($player[1]['value'] == $server->clean_attr($row['attr2'])) {
        if($player[2]['value'] == $server->clean_attr($row['attr3'])) {
            if($player[3]['value'] == $server->clean_attr($row['attr4'])) {
                if($player[4]['value'] == $server->clean_attr($row['attr5'])) {
                    if($player[5]['value'] == $server->clean_attr($row['attr6'])) {
                        //perform action here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

How could I improve such code so it doesn't require all these `if` statements? They seem pretty messy.

Comment: I'd change your attr names if you can for readability

Comment: This post is off-topic for two reasons: it is unclear what this code is doing, and the code is hypothetical ("`//perform action here`")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the attribute names are truly `attr1` through `attr5`, this is nice and terse.

```
$allEqual = true;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    if ($player[$i]['value'] != $server->clean_attr($row['attr' . ($i + 1)]) {
        $allEqual = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($allEqual) {
    // ...
}
```

It doesn't take much tweaking to have a more varied set of attribute names.

```
$attrs = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
$allEqual = true;
for ($attrs as $player => $attr) {
    if ($player[$player]['value'] != $server->clean_attr($row[$attr]) {
        // ... the rest is identical ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the array checks and the conditional: create a walker and store the result of a failed comparison in a separate container. Then check just that stored value:

#### Walker

```
function walk_players( &$player, $key, $context )
{
    $server   = $context['server'];
    $row_attr = $context['row'][ 'attr' . $key + 1 ];

    passed( $player[ $key ][ 'value'] === $server->clean_attr( $row_attr ) );
}
```

#### Storage

```
function passed( $test = NULL )
{
    static $pass = FALSE;

    if ( NULL === $test )
        return $pass;

    if ( FALSE === $test )
        $pass = $test;
}
```

#### Cleaned code

```
$context = array (
    'row'    => $row,
    'server' => $server
);

array_walk( $player, 'walk_players', $context );

if ( passed() )
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since PHP 5.5 you have the function [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php). This function could be used like this:

```
$values = arra_column($player,'value');

foreach($values as $i => $value){
       //stop checking further values
       if($value !== $server->clean_attr($row['attr'.$i+1]) return false;
       //perform action here
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this recommendation is helpful to the user, and provide more information regarding the code that you have displayed.